# Realm Swift duplicates item with primary key -> Threading problem?

Tags: ios, swift, duplicates, realm

I'm using ReamSwift to store data in my iOS application and I have troubles to figure out, why sometimes objects are duplicated in my application.

I use an UUID as primary key on every object. This property is defined in a base class and all the others are subclasses of that.

I use the update approach with a dictionary. So new objects are created and existing should be updated.

I use a central class which holds the Realm object and handles the update. This method could be called from multiple different threads.

This is my base class

```
import RealmSwift
open class RealmObject : Object {
  static let ID_ATTRIBUTE : String = "id"

  @objc dynamic var id : String = ""

  override public static func primaryKey() -> String? {
      return "id"
  }
}
```

Central class managing swift.
This class holds the Realm Object

```
public var realm: Realm {
    
    var tempRealm: Realm?
    do {
        tempRealm = try Realm(configuration: configuration)
    }
    catch let err {
        print("------ERROR----- initializing realm\n \(err)")
    }
    
    if let tempRealm = tempRealm{
        return tempRealm
    }
    
    return self.realm
}
```

This is the update method in the class. As a fallback if the id property is not set, it will be set as it is the primary key

```
func update<T: RealmObject>(_ obj : T, values : [String:Any?] ) -> T? {
    var vals = values
    do {
        var res : T?
        try realm.write {
            if let idattr = vals[T.ID_ATTRIBUTE] as? String {
                if(idattr.isEmpty) {
                    vals[T.ID_ATTRIBUTE] = UUID().uuidString
                }
            } else {
                vals[T.ID_ATTRIBUTE] = UUID().uuidString
            }
            res = realm.create(T.self, value: vals, update: .modified)
        }
        return res
    } catch {
        return nil
    }
}
```

Could calling the update method cause in any case the duplication as I set the primary key of the object? The problem is, I cannot reproduce to find the problem, i just encounter the issue from time to time and in the field from users.
One interesting thing, when a copy is deleted, also the other object will be deleted.
This is the method which deletes objects by id and type

```
func delete<T: RealmObject>(_ id : String, _ type : T.Type) -> Bool {
    do {
        let obj = get(id, T.self)
        if let obj = obj {
            try realm.write {
               realm.delete(obj)
            }
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    } catch {
        return false
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not really clear how your RealmObject model is being used and in particular how the primaryKey is being assigned - e.g. yes, that could be the issue but there's not way for us to tell with the provided code. Typically a primaryKey is done like this `@objc dynamic var _id = ObjectId.generate()` or, in later versions of Realm, like this `@Persisted(primaryKey: true) var id = ObjectId.generate()`. Also, is there a purpose to `required public override init` as it is not needed in the context shown in the question.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. The primary is a string property und usually first set in the realmManager when saving. As outlined in the code above when id property is empty the uuid is set and object is stored. Then the new object is returned and this one should be used by the app then.
Usually it should also work with UUID().uuidString as primary key because this value is unique as well. But somehow my objects get duplicated

The override init method could be removed, it was from testing a different task

Comment: Perhaps I don't understand but the property is set on all objects `static let ID_ATTRIBUTE : String = "id"` and tested for isEmpty with `if let idattr = vals[T.ID_ATTRIBUTE]` and then `if(idattr.isEmpty)` which means it will never be empty. Is that correct?

Comment: yes thats correct, but somehow objects get duplicated with the same id, which should not happen with the update approach as far as I understood the documentation

Comment: There seems to be code which may not be necessary. For example, since ID's cannot be empty per above, this `idattr.isEmpty` will never happen. However, even if it did, it's being populated here `vals[T.ID_ATTRIBUTE] = UUID().uuidString` but if it's not, it's being populated with the exact same code so that appears to be redundant. It's also being checked for nil, which it should never be `idattr = vals[T.ID_ATTRIBUTE] as? String`. I think simplifying the code will help narrow the issue. I suggest refactoring your object `class RealmObject: Object { @objc dynamic var _id = ObjectId.generate()`